# Windows Narrator does not read listbox label

Tags: html, accessibility, narrator

I want a simple markup to be accessible in Windows 10 Narrator. I expect screen-reader to pronounce labelof the `listbox` when you tab into it. Jaws and NVDA does that, but Narrator needs a little more help.

How can I hint Narrator to read `listbox` label?

```
<div id="lll">Foods</div>
<ul role="listbox" aria-labelledby="lll">
    <li role="option" tabIndex="0">Pear</li>
    <li role="option">Buckwheat</li>
</ul>
<ul role="listbox" aria-label="Foods">
    <li role="option" tabIndex="0">Pear</li>
    <li role="option">Buckwheat</li>
</ul>
```

Note: I know Narrator was called a toy many times on this site. List of supported screen-readers is out of my control.

Comment: Are you using Narrator under the latest Win10 update (Anniversary Update) from a month or so ago? Do you have a sample URL for testing? Also, that is not simple markup as it requires JavaScript and ARIA trickery to work. For example, the item receiving focus (by `tabindex=0`) does not have the `aria-labelledby`. The item that is labeled has no way of receiving focus in this example, hence the need to see a URL with all the JS in place.

Comment: Yes, the Narrator is the latest with latest Windows 10. Here's a [test page](https://jsbin.com/najamulaja/edit?output). Looks like Narrator is not reading this by design. Group could be read by clicking `capslock`+`arrow left`...

Comment: Your example just shows bullet lists. Anything with `role=listbox` should be behaving as a combobox or similar to an HTML `<select>`. Your example has no JavaScript, and without that it cannot function as a `listbox`. It also is not styled like one. Do you have an example that matches what you have built? See: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#Listbox